# How to add "" to all words like this : "WORD HERE"

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, notepad

I have a list of 10000 lines like this:

> birthday boy ,boys white, boys ,  for boys
>   boys dress , boys, birthday boys
>   baby girl , baby girl
>   girls , children, girls , boys and girls
>   baby , toddler, baby , kids
>   kids , kids, kids  and tie

How can I enclose all words in double-quotes ("") and turn it into:

> "birthday boy" ,"boys white", "boys" ,  "for boys boys dress" , "boys", "birthday boys baby girl" , "baby girl girls" , "children", "girls" , "boys and girls baby" , "toddler", "baby" , "kids kids" , "kids", "kids  and tie"

I use:

- Notepad++
- Google Spreadsheet
- Excel

Answer (score 3):

If every term is already coma delimited, "find and replace" ',' with ' " , " '
This will work for everything except the first and last.